# problem in displaying an image

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to publish an image..previously I posted the same question but I got that I forgot to add ros::spin()..
But even then there is a problem..It compiled successfully..while running it not displaying an image..

pub.cpp:

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

```
cv_bridge::CvImage cv_image;
cv_image.image = cv::imread("/home/abi/Pictures/attachments/",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv_image.encoding = "bgr8";
sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
cv_image.toImageMsg(ros_image);
```

image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("/static_image/compressed", 3);
ros::Rate loop_rate(5);

while (nh.ok())
{
pub.publish(ros_image);
loop_rate.sleep();
}
}

sub.cpp:
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "bgr8");
//ROS_INFO("Hi");
cv::imshow("view", cv_ptr->image);
cvNamedWindow("view",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
return;
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
cvNamedWindow("view",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/static_image/", 1,imageCallback);
ros::spin();
cvDestroyWindow("view");
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144776/problem-in-displaying-an-image/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work like this:

```
cv::imshow("view", cv_ptr->image);
cv::waitKey(10);
```

To wait for a couple of miliseconds with `waitKey()` when trying to display an image is important in OpenCV, because it allows some time for GUI processing.

You don't really need `cvNamedWindow()` if you use the default parameter `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` because a window is already created by `imshow()`. If you want to use name window anyway, you should stick to the OpenCV C++ API: `cv::namedWindow()`

---

Originally posted by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) with karma: 136 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1